# NumberFormatException while updating database with JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I cannot seem to update my database with values given in my JTable.

My code :

```
public void Update() throws SQLException 
{
    for (int a = 0; a < jTable1.getRowCount(); a++) {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//127.0.0.1:1521/xe","IND","pass");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String query4 = "insert into MONTH_inv VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        String Category = jTable1.getValueAt(a, 0).toString();  
        String Item = jTable1.getValueAt(a, 1).toString();
        int Quantity = Integer.parseInt((String) jTable1.getValueAt(a, 2));
        int avg = Integer.parseInt((String) jTable1.getValueAt(a, 3));
        int ground = Integer.parseInt((String) jTable1.getValueAt(a, 4));

        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query4);
        pstmt.setString(1, Category);
        pstmt.setString(2, Item);
        pstmt.setInt(3, Quantity);
        pstmt.setInt(4, avg);
        pstmt.setInt(5, ground);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }    
}
```

Everything is working fine, but when I click UPDATE button on my GUI, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously, one of the Strings you try to parse as int is null.

You should check `jTable1.getValueAt(a,2)`,  `jTable1.getValueAt(a,3)` and  `jTable1.getValueAt(a,4)` to make sure they are not null.

Comment: How can i check it? When i run the GUI they are not null, but when I System.out.println() for each, nothing happens it shows the same error even if  I remove the pstmt.executeUpdate();

Comment: @Jarvis What do you see if you call `System.out.println(jTable1.getValueAt(a,2))` before calling parseInt?

Comment: 50
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Comment: `NumberFormatException` is thrown by parseInt. What does the `println` show you? (you should call `println` instead of `parseInt` to see what wrong.

Comment: @Jarvis You should print the other values that you try to parse as int : getValueAt(a,3) and getValueAt(a,4)

Comment: I see all the values which I entered

Comment: It works now, a stupid mistake by me... Thank you for your time